# Finding Nano Time in Windows using PHP

Tags: php, unique-id, microtime, nanotime

I would like to create a unique id in php.I used uniqid() but microtime is not helping  because the function is inside a loop and a  set of consecutive results are exactly the same!!
So i am wondering if i can use nano time.In linux it possible using system() function.
Is there any such ways in windows through which I can get nano time in PHP?

Comment: did u consider a usleep(1) in your loop.

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/6zd3WB no duplicates how about `md5(uniqid(rand(), true));`

Comment: Sorry if it was duplicate.I only searched for nanotime.

Comment: Thanks @Dagon md5 worked.no identical string in 5000 values.Thats enough for me.

Comment: Thanks @j_mcnally for telling me about usleep().Its something i always needed to replace sleep.But usleep(1) can never generate a unique string inside small loops.Even with uniqid(2000) i got minimum of 5 identical results.But md5(uniqid(rand(), true)); worked

Comment: its not the md5, that's just a wrapper, to make them pretty, its the rand() prefix that is stopping the duplication

Comment: sweet glad it works, seeding uniqid with rnd better entropy than just time, seems like a good idea.

Comment: perhaps even uniqid("", true) would work too, i think the key here is "moreEntropy" i could be wrong tho.

Comment: @Dagon Yeha I got it.It worked.Very nice idea...I forgot aboun rand().It works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my idea is to add rand() as a prefix like so:

```
md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
```

the md5() is just a wrapper to make them pretty, you can remove it or format the results in other way depending on your need.

Comment: md5 is probably bad in this instance, there is a posibility of a hash collision, which uniqid doesn't have because it uses time for entropy. `uniqid('', true)` or `uniqid(rand(), true)` is probably the safest. Although the prefix is not required but adds to the overall entropy of the generated id.